# Beautiful Soup multiple findAll classes

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Im working on a project to get a database on how many dogs get withdrawn prior to a race.
I need to scrape the data to then write into csv. 
My problem is that the data that i'm scraping has a image instead of text(Between PLC and Greayhound on the webpage).
That means im running 2 different loops to get the info i need and then there hard to concatenate back in its correct place.

Here is the code.

```
import requests
import csv
URL = "https://www.thedogs.com.au/Racing/MeetResults.aspx?meetId=255268"
page = requests.get(URL)
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

#soup.findAll('td', class_='ResultsCenteredCellContents'):

odds=[]
dog = soup.findAll('img' )
for a in dog:

    odds.append(a['src'].strip())


odds1=[]
for b in soup.findAll('td'):
    odds1.append(b.text.strip())
```

So if i could run all the code i need in the one loop that can be written in CSV that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes they are displayed in images but if you notice the images are named according to the number it represents `src="../Images/BoxNumber4.gif` that image represents `4`

```
import requests , csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def SaveAsCsv(list_of_rows,file_name):
    try:
        print('\nSaving CSV Result')
        with open(file_name, 'a',  newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
            writer = csv.writer(outfile)
            writer.writerow(list_of_rows)
            print("rsults saved successully")
    except PermissionError:
        print(f"Please make sure {file_name} is closed \n")

URL = "https://www.thedogs.com.au/Racing/MeetResults.aspx?meetId=255268"
page = requests.get(URL, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
tables = soup.findAll('table',{'id':"gvRaceResults"}) # getting all 11 tabs
for  table_index , table in enumerate(tables,1): 
    print(f'Getting tab {table_index} out of {len(tables)} ')
    rows = table.findAll('tr')
    header_row = [row.text.strip() for row in rows[0].findAll('th')]
    SaveAsCsv(header_row , 'thedogs.csv')
    for index , row in enumerate(rows[1:],1):
            print(f'Getting row {index} out of {len(rows[1:])} ')
            row_list = []
            colms = row.findAll('td')
            for col in colms :
                    if  'ResultsContentsNumber' in col.attrs['class']:
                            image_src = col.find('img').get('src') #src="../Images/BoxNumber4.gif">
                            image_num = image_src.split('BoxNumber')[1].split('.')[0] # 4
                            row_list.append(image_num)
                            continue
                    row_list.append(col.text.strip())
            SaveAsCsv(row_list , 'thedogs.csv')
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Great, thats works. Good stuff @user:5794970. The only issue i have is that on the webpage there are 11 tabs with results for different races from that track. Were would the best positioning be to loop through all those races?

Comment: @MBill instead of using `.find('table',{'id':"gvRaceResults"})` use `find_all` and loop through each table . Please accept the answer

Comment: That work around gives this error. `-> 1884             "ResultSet object has no attribute '%s'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?" % key`